# Maintain scroll position after search

Tags: php, html

I have a search bar on my page, however it is about half way down, and when you submit a search query, the page scrolls back to the top.

Is there a way to get the page to stay where the user was when they search? My search is on the same page, and all of the content also stays on the page.

This is my current search code:

```
$search=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['search']);


//- Queries the table to get content from rows - 

$QuerySelect =  "SELECT thumbnail,image,title,category,description 
                 FROM homepage 
                 WHERE category LIKE '%$search%' ";

//----------------- QUERY the TABLE, store THE CONTENT IN A PHP VARIABLE -----------------
$result = mysql_query($QuerySelect);
```

HTML :

```
<div class="searchcontainer">
<form method="post" action="index.php">
<input type="text" class="input" name="search" size="40" placeholder="Search by Category...">
<input type="submit" class="button" name="Submit" value="Search" id="Submit" >
</form>
</div>
<?php
$numrows = mysql_num_rows ($result );
if($numrows == 0){
```

Javascript & JQuery code is fine.

Comment: Is the scroll position fixed or your searchbar top position can change?

Comment: I need the search to stay where it is

Comment: Are you posting back to the page you are currently on? If you are then you can try making your action be `index.php#my-form` and give your form an ID of `my-form`. Of course change my-form to whatever you want.

Comment: You can search the top of the search bar on page load and scroll to that position or preserve page scroll position between requests is not the same solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are posting to the same page you are on, you can make your action be `index.php#my-form` and give your form an ID of `my-form`. Of course change my-form to whatever you want.